# Find IP address of hosting via cpanel?

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, ip-address

Is it possible to tell the IP of the hosting space via cpanel?

A client of a client has setup the domain and setup a sub domain (ie blog.domain.com). It's been hard work to get any kind of passwords out of them for anything.

Currently the A-record for the subdomain isn't setup so it's pointing to the default space rather than the subdomain space. So I need to tell them the IP address of the hosting space for the subdomain. The files are already uploaded and are there ready.

Comment: It would probably be simpler to just use your web host's DNS servers. This is what most people do, so when they create the subdomain both the DNS records and vhost configurations are generated automatically.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I can't, I only have access to the cpanel.

Comment: That's all you need access to. cPanel will do all of that for you if you're using your web host's DNS servers. You shouldn't have to manually create the A record.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I'm getting an internal error but can't tell if it's pointing to my files.

Comment: Check your server logs to see what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find the IP address via the CP. And basically the subdomain will follow the root IP, so if the IP of your subdomain will same with your root IP. It will automatically generated when you created your subdomain via CPanel. If you have further problem, plesae contact your ISP. good luck. :)